# Regular expression not working in google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Im trying to build a regular expression to capture URLs which contain a certain parameter `7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B`

Ive set up a simple regex to capture a URL with anything before and anything after this parameter (just just all URLs which contain this parameter). Ive tested this on an online checker: http://scriptular.com/ and seems to work fine. However google analytics is saying this is invalid when i try to use it. Any idea what is causing this?

Url will be in the format

```
/home/index?x=23908123890123&y=kjdfhjhsfd&z=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B&p=kljdaslkjasd
```

so i just want to capture URLs that contain that specific "z" parameter.

**regex**

```
^.+(?=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B).+$
```

Comment: @anubhava updated to include a URL example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need

```
^.+=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B.+$
```

Or (a bit safer):

```
^.+=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B($|&.+$)
```

And I think you can even use

```
=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B($|&)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6sL0/1)

Your regex is invalid because GA regex flavor does not support look-arounds (and you have a `(?=...)` positive look-ahead in yours).

Here is a good [GA regex cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/jay-taylor/cheat-sheets/google-analytics-regular-expressions/).

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the help. That link is really handy too, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

To match `/home/index?x=23908123890123&y=kjdfhjhsfd&z=7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B&p=kljdaslkjasd` you can use:

```
\S*7136D38A-AA70-434E-A705-0F5C6D072A3B\S*
```